# placing few hundred icons on googlemap is very very slow - Using GMap V3

Tags: google-maps

I am facing a problem with googlemaps. My search returns 676 Hotels in Germany. But if I try to place these hotel on GoogleMap.
I workrs but icon placing is very very slow. and zoom is also some how strange if too many hotels are placed on map.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you referring to the Google Maps API? Which version of the API are you using (V2 or V3)? In what browsers do you find it slow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to tackle this problem is to only create the markers when needed.

Take a look at this example and the documentation for marker manager.

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markermanager/1.0/examples/weather_map.html

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markermanager/1.0/docs/reference.html

One solution is to create more markers as you zoom in, thus not having tons of markers displayed at once.